# Imbalance dataset: Should I use oversampling technique before or after feature selection?

Tags: feature-selection, oversampling

I wonder if it is best to use oversampling techniques such as ADASYN before feature selection steps or after. Thanks

Comment: I have a similar question using a pipeline: Should SelectKbest be applied before or after the under/oversampling step? Hope s.o. will answer our question soon :) Cheers

Comment: here is an answer I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63375860/sampling-before-or-after-feature-selection but id like to have it confirmed